# Comment anchor links get "visited" highlighting - is this supposed to happen?

Tags: bug, comments, design

I just noticed that visiting a comment via its anchor link, which is placed on the time stamp, causes the link to get the blue "visited" colour on SO. As it's not visible on meta, [here's a random example from the main site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31022852/what-exception-should-be-thrown-when-there-is-no-object-associated-with-a-key#comment50070541_31022852). I noticed it while navigating to a reply via the inbox, but it seems to happen regardless of how one arrives at a comment.

As far as I remember this wasn't always the case; at least for inbox notifications. I'm not sure if it was introduced with the new design or is a more recent change, or if I misremember or simply never noticed this. If it is intentional, I'd like for SO to reconsider that decision - it's not useful to know if one has "visited" a comment or not, but leads to inconsistent coloration of the time stamps which is somewhat distracting as the username is less distinct from the timestamp, making both a bit harder to parse.

Tagging this as a bug in case it is not intentional, if it is please consider this to be a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's a bug or not, but I know how to fix it:

**Step 1:** Remove this CSS style:

```css
.post-text a:visited,.comment-text a:not(.comment-user):visited{
    color:#0c65a5
}
```

**Step 2:** Replace it with this simpler style, which does not have the same issue:

```css
.post-text a:visited,.comment-copy a:visited{
    color:#0c65a5
}
```

---

Anyway, while waiting for SE to fix this properly, I've added the following CSS fix to [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.32:

```css
body .comment-date a.comment-link,
body .comment-date a.comment-link:visited {
    color: inherit;
}
```

(The reason for the funny selector is that it needs to be more specific than `.comment-text a:not(.comment-user):visited` in order to override it.  I could've just used `!important`, but I prefer to avoid it whenever possible, since it can easily become an "addiction" — the only way to override an `!important` rule is with another `!important` rule, so once you start using it, you may find yourself needing it more and more.)